# how to list the actual rules in effect for modprobe?

Tags: modprobe

we have several places can put the rules for modprobe:

1. /lib/modprobe.d/*.conf
2. /etc/modprobe.d/*.conf
3. /run/modprobe.d/*.conf
4. boot parameters

There can be multiple places configuring the same module.

I wondering if there is a tool can print all the rules actually in action. If it cannot print the install or remove, I am ok with it. If it cannot look at the boot parameters, it is also ok. But at least I want a full blacklist merged from all the places. I want to see all the module parameters, if not merged, it should be at least in the correct order (last one wins).

[Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/62316/how-do-i-list-loaded-linux-module-parameter-values) people already discussed means to print the actual module parameters for already loaded modules. But 1. the values can still come from default values (most of them are from default); Here I just want to see the value different from default value. 2. I also need the value for unloaded modules.

More over their methods do no show blacklist either.

I am kind of expecting the modprobe will have some diagnostic mode to just print what it is going to do instead of really loading modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After carefully digging into the modprobe man page, I found this:

```
modprobe --showconfig
```

It does exactly I want. It prints out all of the configurations without executing anything.